# remove a part of circular div from bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm working with some css shapes and I made a circular div. 
I have some specific design requirements which states that the upper half portion of the circular div should be visible and should be aligned to the bottom of the div.
The lower(below bottom) half should be hidden.

The issue I want to remove the lower half of the circular div. 
It overlaps in the next div.

I tried `z-index` but still progress here's my code.

```css
    .type1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        left: -100px;
        top: 280px;
        background: yellow;
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .text{
          margin-left: 30%;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
```

```html
     <div style='background-image:url("https://i.imgsafe.org/69e56d5ec8.jpg");height: 600px;position:relative;'>
      <div class="circleBase type1">
          
           <h1 class="text">
           some text inside
           </h1>
        </div>
        </div>  
       <div>
       <h1>
       some other text
       </h1>
       </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mq8t7kpy/)

Comment: tried `overflow:hidden` on the container div?

Comment: o dude thanks man!!1 could write this in separate answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` needs to be used here

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasinallana/mq8t7kpy/2/)

Comment: @Lee the answer was posted as a comment , but was requested by the OP to be posted as an answer

Comment: I know, I read that. But your JSFiddle link doesn't show anything different, and doesn't show an answer to the question, so it's not helpful...

Comment: @Lee whoops forgot to sign-in and save it before posting it here , updated it , please check now

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:hidden` like here:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/mq8t7kpy/1/)

Comment: appreciated..:)